# Get all items or data from API where they need to meet a condition to be fetched

Tags: javascript, json, api, axios

I want to display a list of all items or data from an API source where the VirtualOrganization (or some other data) is the one i specify (like ATCclub). I use Axios to get the data.

Baicicly I only want to only fetch the JSON data from the API where the VirtualOrganization is the right one, and then display it.

Here is my code:

```js
let data;
axios.get(URLBASE + '/flights/' + expert + '?apikey=' + APIKEY, {
    params: {
        virtualOrganization: "ATCclub"
    }
  })
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.result);
     if (response.data.result.virtualOrganization === "ATCclub") {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.result.virtualOrganization.array.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = response.data.result.username;
            document.getElementById("aircraftId").innerHTML = response.data.result.aircraftId;
            document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = response.data.result.heading;
            document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = response.data.result.latitude;
            document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = response.data.result.longitude;
            document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = response.data.result.speed;
            document.getElementById("altitude").innerHTML = response.data.result.altitude;
        }
    }
    
    
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

NOTE: I have managed to display one row from the JSON.

Comment: How does the response looks like?

Comment: I get a response of all JSON rows in the console and nothing works to send to the html page, but that's not what I want

Comment: How do you choose the row in response?? @Daniel

Comment: if I want to output something from one row, I do: response.data.result[0].username.
As you saw, I just use a [] and put a number there, but if I want to get all the rows which have the same virtualOrganization, I can't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after someone sent me a answer to "filter it after".
Then I came up with this:

```js
// resF (result of flights)
const resF = response.data.result.filter(function (e){
        return e.virtualOrganization === "ATCclub";
    });
```